# Is sencha touch a better option than jquery mobile or Jqtouch?

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch

As there are many options available over for development of touch mobile websites. So is Sencha Touch a better option than JQuery mobile or JQtouch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best cross-mobile javascript framework (iPhone/Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android)

Comment: Not a duplicate anymore!

Comment: This is very opinion based - at a minimum, state your use case with some specific needs that the different frameworks could address...

Answer (score 3):

This chart might be helpful for you.

[Mobile framework comparison Chart](http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, the main good reasons for using Sencha Touch would be because:

- It offers a bit more like lots of icons, or built-in maps.
- It supports a more MVC style application design.

You should check these links which are quite interesting:

- http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/jqtouch-vs-sencha-touch-vs-jquery.html
- http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/jqtouch-vs-jquery-mobile.html

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your particular requirements i.e. what kind of an app you are building. If you compare sencha touch and jqmobile then both have their own pros and cons. I'd go with sencha for more graphically appealing complicated interactive apps but will go with jquerymobile for smaller apps which need simple forms and pages and need to be built really quickly.

Check this out:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/sencha-touch-v-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch and Jquery Mobile has it own benefits.
Briefly to explain differences:

1. Sencha require developers to know Javascript, Whereas Jquery mobile developers should know html5, css3.
2. Sencha Touch provides framework  to build apps that work on iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone.
3. Sencha provide native look and like feeling and is recommended in case we are building hybrid mobile application.
4. Sencha graphical performance  is fast and fluid on mobile devices better than JQuery Mobile
5. JQuery is Easy to develop.
6. JQuery Mobile works on wide variety of browsers.
7. JQuery Mobile Lots of 3rd party extensions - as you'd expect from the jQuery community

Refer this url it has explained.  http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/

Regards,
Cleo

Answer (score 0):

They both have their own advantages and disadvantages. IF you want better UI then you have to use Sencha but for better functionality the JQuery is better. 
You can check [here](http://www.solidstategroup.com/blog/building-for-mobile-jquery-mobile-and-sencha-touch-framework-comparison/%22Here%22) for more details.